# Error - A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have started today to learn about the SQL connection in C# programming. And I tried some basic thing like the Insert, Delete etc.

And I wanted to try the same thing in another project but I have a problem. Because It shows me an error that I can't solve :(

Error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Artikujt.Form1.con'.

Here is my code (I just started to connect it with the Database in SQL)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Artikujt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
        DataSet dsl = new DataSet();    

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    
    }
}
```

The error is in this code at the variable `con`

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
```

I created the Database in SQL (in Visual Studio)... I also added the Data Source. I did the exact thing that I did before.... but it isn't working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says. You cannot use `con` in your initialization of `da` because it will only be created during an instance creation. You will need to create `con` as `static` or put your initialization lines in your constructor.

**HOWEVER**, you should probably not do this in practice as you are just asking for somebody to open a `SqlConnection` and leave it open. You should probably fall more into the practice of creating your connections using a `using` block to take advantage of the disposing pattern

Static:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
    DataSet dsl = new DataSet();    


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Or instantiation in the constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet dsl;  

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
        dsl = new DataSet();  
    }
}
```

I will let you [research the using block yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You must put your initialization code inside the constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
            SqlConnection con = null; 
            SqlDataAdapter da = null; 
            DataSet dsl =  null;     


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
                 da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
                dsl = new DataSet();    
            }
}
```

You can not access con in the field initializer `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);` cause it's not static. The error is self explanatory. The issue is not SQL related it is c# related, I would recomment to revisit the C#.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move this initialization into the constructor.

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet dsl;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con)
    dsl = new DataSet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
use inside any method or event
like as bellow example button event

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Drawing;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Windows.Forms;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace Artikujt
    {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial              Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    DataSet dsl = new DataSet();    

    public Form1()
    {
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
        InitializeComponent();
    }  

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM    tblArtikujt",           con);
     }  
}
```

}

Comment: here con method inside the connection class so this error solved

Answer (score 0):

```
static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TALY-PC;Initial Catalog=Katalogi;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblArtikujt", con);
DataSet dsl = new DataSet();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```