# How to add new ObservableCollection from Icommand command?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a simple MVVM project I am learning on. I am trying to add to an ObservableCollection through an ICommand command, but I am unable to?

MainWindow.cs I haven't added anything*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <Local:ViewModel></Local:ViewModel>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lstNames" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding View_}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="Setting_Items">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Setting_A"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding View_String}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

   <TextBox Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="145,195,0,0" 
            Name="textBox1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="120" />
  <ComboBox Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="269,195,0,0" 
            Name="My_ComboBox" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="222"     
            ItemsSource="{Binding View_}"/>
    <Button Content="Message Text" 
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="52,166,0,0" 
            Name="button1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}"
            Command="{Binding Print_Line}"/>
    <Button Content="Add To Drop"
            Height="23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="52,195,0,0" 
            Name="button2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" 
            />


</Grid>
```

---

```
    public class View
{
    public string View_String {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
    public class SimpleDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<object> _executeDelegate;

    public SimpleDelegateCommand(Action<object> executeDelegate)
    {
        _executeDelegate = executeDelegate;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeDelegate(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

---

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<View> _View;

    public string _View_String { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<View> View_
    {
        get { return _View; }
        set { _View = value; }
    }

    ICommand _Print_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) => MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()));

    ICommand _Add_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) =>
         View_ = new ObservableCollection<View>() /////////Error HERE
        {
            new View(){View_String = x.ToString()}
        }
        );


    public ViewModel()
    {
        View_ = new ObservableCollection<View>()
        {
            new View(){View_String = "Setting 1"},
            new View(){View_String = "Setting 2"}
        };
    }

    public ICommand Print_Line { get { return _Print_Line; } }
    public ICommand Add_Line { get { return _Add_Line; } }
}
```

How do I go about adding to my ObservableCollection using an ICommand command? or how do I go about it?

Also, how do you perform multiple tasks using an ICommand command, for example:
        ICommand _Print_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) => MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()); MessageBox.Show("Second task"));

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: no, I just don't understand enough about WPF core, but I know there is a stupid simple fix to this. I just want to add to my ObservableCollection from a button click, text from textbox! lol

Comment: I don't understand why I can't just simply call a private function>>> ICommand _Print_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) => { Function();});

Comment: you can do it but not before your class is constructed, this is just not wpf but dotnet in general. Even when you initiaze the command in constructor, it will get called only when you execute it...

Comment: Yeah I got it now, thank you.

Command_Test = new SimpleDelegateCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMessage));

Comment: great.. pls accept the answer inorder to help others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perform multiple tasks:

```
_Print_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) => {
   MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());  
   MessageBox.Show("Second task");
 });
```

Add private set to your command's field, for access it just from your class

```
private ICommand print_Line;
public ICommand Print_Line { 
                             get { return print_Line; } 
                             private set { print_Line = value; } 
                           }

private ICommand add_Line;
public ICommand Add_Line  { 
                             get { return add_Line; } 
                             private set { add_Line = value; } 
                          }
```

maybe can help this way too:

```
private ICommand print_Line;
public ICommand Print_Line { get { return print_Line; } }

private ICommand add_Line;
public ICommand Add_Line{ get { return add_Line; } }
```

Comment: sorry, im tired, what do you mean with that? :D

Comment: Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'WpfApplication1.ViewModel.View_.get'

Comment: I am trying to add the textbox string to my ObservableCollection "View_", which I haven't bounded yet.

Comment: I don't understand, can you give me a tiny example?

Comment: You forget the backing field, as i think. Please try the code above. :)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `Commands` Initialization code inside the `constructor` of your `ViewModel` class. You are trying to access View_ which is not yet constructed yet and hence giving error. Object initializer outside constructor should not call the instance methods/properties as the class is not constructed till that time.

```
ICommand _Print_Line;

ICommand _Add_Line;


public ViewModel()
{
    _Print_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) => MessageBox.Show(x.ToString()));

    _Add_Line = new SimpleDelegateCommand((x) =>
     View_ = new ObservableCollection<View>() /////////Error HERE
    {
        new View(){View_String = x.ToString()}
    }
    );

    View_ = new ObservableCollection<View>()
    {
        new View(){View_String = "Setting 1"},
        new View(){View_String = "Setting 2"}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is barely readable. The error is pretty straight forward. When you initialize a field, you cannot reference a non-static field. 
ICommand _Add_Line is an instance field. Just as _View is. If you want to reference it, initialize the ICommand _Add_Line within the constructor of the class. Every time you call a non-static field or method, you need an instance of that class to get its value.
There are several answers on this issue on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770287/error-a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-pr)

Comment: Yeah, this 'coding conventions' you are using are not my cup of tea. Why not a simple camelCase?!

Comment: Basically because I am brand new to WPF coming from Windows forms which I started a few months back, IDK what camelCase is.

Comment: Just forget about _ charter. I haven't seen that much Windows forms code, but I know it's not a C# favorite. 
[From msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) 
When an identifier consists of multiple words, do not use separators, such as underscores ("_") or hyphens ("-"), between words. Instead, use casing to indicate the beginning of each word.

Comment: isn't that just preference, I thought that makes sense.

Easy to remember.