# Add to ObservableCollection with ICommand

Tags: c#, addition, observablecollection, icommand

I have a problem with adding items to ObservableCollection via ICommand.
There is second Window for editing this ObservableCollection.
And when i add new Items ,the ListView in the second window show's the new item, but the 1st Window don't.
How can i add to my Obseravle Collection from my command ?

Here is my ObservableCollection:

```
 public  class ProductExtrasObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>
{
    public AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand { get; set; }
    public DeleteExtrasProductCommand DeleteExtrasProductCommand { get; set; }


    public ProductExtrasObservableCollection() : base()
    {
        AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand = new AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand(this);
        DeleteExtrasProductCommand = new DeleteExtrasProductCommand(this);

        Add(new ProductViewModel(new Product { Name = "Sugar", Price = 0.05, IsDrink = false }) { IsChecked = false } );
        Add(new ProductViewModel(new Product { Name = "Milk", Price = 0.2, IsDrink = false }) { IsChecked = false });
        Add(new ProductViewModel(new Product { Name = "Cream", Price = 0.1, IsDrink = false }) { IsChecked = false });
        Add(new ProductViewModel(new Product { Name = "Canela", Price = 0.15, IsDrink = false }) { IsChecked = false });
    }
}
```

}

And this is my class with the command:

```
 public  class AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand : ICommand
{
    ProductExtrasObservableCollection Collection { get; set; }

    public AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand(ProductExtrasObservableCollection Coll)
    {
        this.Collection = Coll;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       Collection.Add(new ProductViewModel(parameter as Product));
    }

}
```

This is XAML for the button:

```
<Button  
        Content="Add to Extras"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="458,184,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="88" 
        Height="60" 
        Command="{Binding AddToExtrasObservableCollectionCommand, Source={StaticResource ExtrasData}}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding NewProduct, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new ObservableCollection from Icommand command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457120/how-to-add-new-observablecollection-from-icommand-command)

Comment: It's maybe the same question but when try to do it this way the same problem happend. I'm not sure how to do it exactly. So if you have example or something it would be great. Thank you for the time you spend!

Comment: If you say the items show in the second window, then you probably didn't set the binding to you list in the first window